# How to manage a mutex in an asynchronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, mutex, linq-to-twitter

I have ported my old HttpHandler (.ashx) TwitterFeed code to a WebAPI application.  The core of the code uses the excellent Linq2Twitter package (https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/).  Part of the port involved upgrading this component from version 2 to version 3, which now provides a number of asynchronous method calls - which are new to me.  Here is the basic controller:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Status>> 
GetTweets(int count, bool includeRetweets, bool excludeReplies)
{
   var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
   {
      CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
      {
         ConsumerKey       = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"],
         ConsumerSecret    = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKeySecret"],
         AccessToken       = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessToken"],
         AccessTokenSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessTokenSecret"]
      }
   };

   var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);

   var tweets =
      await
      (from tweet in ctx.Status
         where (
            (tweet.Type == StatusType.Home)
            && (tweet.ExcludeReplies == excludeReplies)
            && (tweet.IncludeMyRetweet == includeRetweets)
            && (tweet.Count == count)
         )
      select tweet)
      .ToListAsync();

   return tweets;
}
```

This works fine, but previously, I had cached the results to avoid 'over calling' the Twitter API.  It is here that I have run into a problem (more to do with my lack of understanding of the asynchronous protocol than anything else I suspect).

In overview, what I want to do is to first check the cache, if data doesn't exists, then rehydrate the cache and return the data to the caller (web page).  Here is my attempt at the code

```
public class TwitterController : ApiController {

   private const string CacheKey = "TwitterFeed";

   public async Task<IEnumerable<Status>>
   GetTweets(int count, bool includeRetweets, bool excludeReplies)
   {
      var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
      var tweets = await GetTweetData(context, count, includeRetweets, excludeReplies);
      return tweets;
   }

   private async Task<IEnumerable<Status>>
   GetTweetData(HttpContext context, int count, bool includeRetweets, bool excludeReplies)
   {
      var cache = context.Cache;
      Mutex mutex = null;
      bool iOwnMutex = false;
      IEnumerable<Status> data = (IEnumerable<Status>)cache[CacheKey];

      // Start check to see if available on cache
      if (data == null)
      {
         try
         {
            // Lock base on resource key
            mutex = new Mutex(true, CacheKey);

            // Wait until it is safe to enter (someone else might already be
            // doing this), but also add 30 seconds max.
            iOwnMutex = mutex.WaitOne(30000);

            // Now let's see if some one else has added it...
            data = (IEnumerable<Status>)cache[CacheKey];

            // They did, so send it...
            if (data != null)
            {
               return data;
            }

            if (iOwnMutex)
            {
               // Still not there, so now is the time to look for it!
               data = await CallTwitterApi(count, includeRetweets, excludeReplies);

               cache.Remove(CacheKey);
               cache.Add(CacheKey, data, null, GetTwitterExpiryDate(),
                  TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
         }
         finally
         {
            // Release the Mutex.
            if ((mutex != null) && (iOwnMutex))
            {
               // The following line throws the error:
               // Object synchronization method was called from an
               // unsynchronized block of code.
               mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
         }
      }

      return data;
   }

   private DateTime GetTwitterExpiryDate()
   {
      string szExpiry = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterCacheExpiry"];
      int expiry = Int32.Parse(szExpiry);
      return DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expiry);
   }

   private async Task<IEnumerable<Status>>
   CallTwitterApi(int count, bool includeRetweets, bool excludeReplies)
   {
      var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
      {
         CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
         {
            ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"],
            ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKeySecret"],
            AccessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessToken"],
            AccessTokenSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessTokenSecret"]
         }
      };

      var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);

      var tweets =
         await
         (from tweet in ctx.Status
          where (
             (tweet.Type == StatusType.Home)
             && (tweet.ExcludeReplies == excludeReplies)
             && (tweet.IncludeMyRetweet == includeRetweets)
             && (tweet.Count == count)
             && (tweet.RetweetCount < 1)
          )
          select tweet)
         .ToListAsync();

      return tweets;
   }

}
```

The problem occurs in the finally code block where the Mutex is released (though I have concerns about the overall pattern and approach of the GetTweetData() method):

```
if ((mutex != null) && (iOwnMutex))
{
    // The following line throws the error:
    // Object synchronization method was called from an
    // unsynchronized block of code.
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

If I comment out the line, the code works correctly, but (I assume) I should release the Mutex having created it.  From what I have found out, this problem is related to the thread changing between creating and releasing the mutex.

Because of my lack of general knowledge on asynchronous coding, I am not sure a) if the pattern I'm using is viable and b) if it is, how I address the problem.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a mutex like that isn't going to work. For one thing, a `Mutex` is thread-affine, so it can't be used with `async` code.

Other problems I noticed:

- `Cache` is threadsafe, so it shouldn't need a mutex (or any other protection) anyway.
- Asynchronous methods should follow the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

There is one major tip regarding caching: when you just have an in-memory cache, then cache the *task* rather than the resulting data. On a side note, I have to wonder whether `HttpContext.Cache` is the best cache to use, but I'll leave it as-is since your question is more about how asynchronous code changes caching patterns.

So, I'd recommend something like this:

```
private const string CacheKey = "TwitterFeed";

public Task<IEnumerable<Status>> GetTweetsAsync(int count, bool includeRetweets, bool excludeReplies)
{
  var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
  return GetTweetDataAsync(context, count, includeRetweets, excludeReplies);
}

private Task<IEnumerable<Status>> GetTweetDataAsync(HttpContext context, int count, bool includeRetweets, bool excludeReplies)
{
  var cache = context.Cache;
  Task<IEnumerable<Status>> data = cache[CacheKey] as Task<IEnumerable<Status>>;
  if (data != null)
    return data;
  data = CallTwitterApiAsync(count, includeRetweets, excludeReplies);
  cache.Insert(CacheKey, data, null, GetTwitterExpiryDate(), TimeSpan.Zero);
  return data;
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<Status>> CallTwitterApiAsync(int count, bool includeRetweets, bool excludeReplies)
{
  ...
}
```

There's a small possibility that if two different requests (from two different sessions) request the same twitter feed at the same exact time, that the feed will be requested twice. But I wouldn't lose sleep over it.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, very helpful.  The reason I had tried to implement the Mutex was to avoid two Twitter requests from two sessions.  The Twitter feed is displayed on every page of the web site, so I reasoned that if the feed took say 5 seconds to return, then the chances of two  simultaneous requests was quite high, but I take your point.  Thanks again very your detailed explanation and example.

Comment: If you cache the task, then there is a *very* low probability that the Twitter feed will be requested twice. This is because the task is added to the cache as soon as the download is *started*, not when it is *completed*.

Comment: That's actually fantastically clever.  I assume because it is caching a Task, even if another process makes the request against the cache before it has downloaded, then it simply awaits for the Task to respond?  I find that hard to comprehend that that is even possible!

Comment: Yes. Once the (incomplete) task is added to the cache, then any other threads can read that task from the cache. A task can be awaited by any number of methods simultaneously, and they will all continue when the task completes. Also, after the task is completed, awaiting the task does not yield; instead, the await follows a [fast path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/15/async-ctp-refresh-design-changes.aspx) and continues executing synchronously. So I like storing tasks in caches, but it only can be done with in-memory caches.